# What is the default CSS3 animation timing function?

Tags: css, css-animations

In the following animation, I haven't specified a timing function, such as linear or ease-in.  It seems to default to ease-in, since it slows down once it begins reaching 0%.  What is the actual timing function that is being used in this case (or the default)?

```
@-webkit-keyframes goleft { 
    0% { left:400px; } 
    100% { left:0px; } 
}

. goleft {
    -webkit-animation: goleft 10s infinite;
    animation: goleft 10s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value is `ease` according to the [W3 docs on the subject](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-animations-20120403/#animation-timing-function-property)

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS3 specification for Animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-timing-function-property) spells it out simply:

> Name: animation-timing-function
>   Initial: 'ease'